# Getting ID of list element of external HTML file using jQuery(AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an external HTML file which contains only an unordered list with a few list elements like this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="list-1"></li>
    <li id="list-2"></li>
    <li id="list-3"></li>
    <li id="list-4"></li>
    <li id="list-5"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the **ID** of those list elements `without loading them into the DOM` of my main HTML file using jQuery(AJAX).

Comment: use virtual dom element and find the desired one from it.

Comment: You should try with Curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX to retrieve the HTML, then create a jQuery object from the returned HTML and loop through them to get their `id` attributes, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/yourpage.html',
  success: function(html) {
    $(html).find('li').each(function() {
      var id = this.id;
      // use the id here...          
    })
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` to build an array of the `id` values, it all depends on your use case

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
$('li').each(function(){
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="list-1">a</li>
    <li id="list-2">b</li>
    <li id="list-3">c</li>
    <li id="list-4">d</li>
    <li id="list-5">e</li>
</ul>
<button>Click Me</button>
```